# Add background image to paragraph in rich text editor tiny mce

Tags: css, tinymce, umbraco

I have spent hours to think how to get this thing working without any success , what I want to add background image to selected paragraph in tiny mce, I can do that using style dropdown in rich text editor but I want to extend that image dynamically when the selected paragraph text extend. This can be done using 3 divs like:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="center"><p></p></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

But the issue is I can't do that using rich text editor tiny mce, and I want to give that ability to front end user who can just select the paragaraph and set the styling from dropdown in order to show the background image to that paragraph on the website, I have included the background image just for guidance, can any one provide any assistance or suggestions on how to get this thing working. Here's the background image:
[image]

Comment: can you descirbe step-by-step what the user can do? and what the desired output will be?

Comment: the user is entering text in the tiny mce as paragraphs , i want each paragraph to appear in the above image

Comment: sry, but i do not understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Did anyone resolve this or find a solution? Looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ['Template' plugin for TinyMCE](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/enabling-the-%27template%27-plugin-for-tinymce)

or ['MySnippets' package for TinyMCE](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/mysnippets-for-tinymce)

hope this helps